# aidl.exe Error while creating directories: Invalid argument

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-support-library, in-app-billing

I updated my sdk yesterday and I encountered a problem. Google Play Library seems to be broken. I couldn't understand the error and I couldn't find how to solve this problem. Any idea how to solve this problem without waiting Google?

```
aidl.exe E  3628  7164 io_delegate.cpp:102] Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
```

[Screenshot of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUcZ7.png)

Edit: As I see, this is a bug on 24.0.0 but still I can't understand how to solve this?

Edit2: My codes worked before the update.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202972

Comment: Can you go back to the last working version until this is fixed?

Comment: how to find older versions of support libraries or play billing libraries?

Answer (score 7):

Today ,Use Eclipse import Project

```
Error while creating directories: Invalid argument
```

Search Google

solve this problem：

1. remove android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.0-preview
2. Restart the Eclispe
3. The project is build sucess;

Answer (score 3):

I solve a problem using very easy way. Go ...\sdk\build-tools and remove 24.0.0. This solves the problem.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W09qK.png)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be error in **aidl** tool (or some change that is incompatible with build process). I have replaced **aidl** in 24.0.0 build tools with **aidl** from 23.0.0 and was able to compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following code in my `android{}` section of my project's gradle.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
    }
}
```